# Python Firebase SDK on User Manipulation for Multi-tenancy (Google Identity Platform)

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to achieve what's written exactly on ["Migrating users between projects and tenants"](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/migrate-users-between-projects-tenants). I have written the Node.js version and its implementation is highly straightforward. You authenticalte for a tenant (tenant A), authenticate for another tenant (tenant B), retrieve user from tenant A, create by copying the user JSON instance, and import to tenant B.

The problem for me is however, I would like to write this in Python3, and there is no documentation or examples to be found about this issue specifically as far as I could find.
What is the typically preferred, elegant way to achieve the same thing on Python3?

I am guessing one possible approach would look something like this:

```py
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import tenant_mgt
from firebase_admin.auth import import_users, delete_users, ImportUserRecord

app = firebase_admin.initialize_app()
tenants = [t.tenant_id for t in tenant_mgt.list_tenants(app=app).iterate_all()]

source_tenant = tenants[0]
target_tenant = tenants[1]

source_client = tenant_mgt.auth_for_tenant(source_tenant, app=app)
target_client = tenant_mgt.auth_for_tenant(target_tenant, app=app)

# out: instances of ExportUserRecord
users = [u for u in source_tenant.list_users(max_results=1000).iterate_all()]

# maybe generate ImportUserRecord here
new_users = []
for u in users:
    new_user = ImportUserRecord(...some_appropriate_constructor_args...)
    new_users.append(new_user)

# import?
```

Comment: Sounds like your solution is working as intended. Is there something you feel is "unelegant" in your solution?